# Cannot get dialogsProvider in app config

Tags: angularjs

In my app config below, I want to inject and use [dialogsProvider](https://github.com/m-e-conroy/angular-dialog-service):

**app.config.js**

```
import app from './app.module';

app.config(['$compileProvider', '$filterProvider', '$provide', '$httpProvider',
            'dashboardResolverProvider','dialogsProvider', 'localStorageServiceProvider','ROUTER',
            '$translateProvider',

    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, routeResolverProvider, $controllerProvider,
              $compileProvider, $filterProvider, $provide, $httpProvider, 
              dashboardResolverProvider, dialogsProvider, localStorageServiceProvider, ROUTER, $translateProvider) {

        dialogsProvider.useBackdrop(true);
        dialogsProvider.useEscClose(true);
        dialogsProvider.useCopy(false);
        dialogsProvider.setSize("sm");
```

After webpack bundle built, I opened web browser and saw this error in the console:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'useBackdrop' of undefined`

Obviously, the `dialogsProvider` is not injected. How to get it injected?

**app.js**

```
import './app.module';
import './app.config';
import './app.run';
import './controllers/FirstController'
import './directives/FirstDirective'
...
angular.bootstrap(document, ['hepicApp']);
```

**app.module.js**

```
import 'angular';
...
import 'angular-dialog-service';
...
var app = angular.module('hepicApp', [
  'dialogs.main',
  ...
]);
export default app;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'routeResolverProvider', '$controllerProvider','$compileProvider', '$filterProvider', '$provide', '$httpProvider',
        'dashboardResolverProvider','dialogsProvider', 'localStorageServiceProvider','ROUTER',
        '$translateProvider',

function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, routeResolverProvider, $controllerProvider,
          $compileProvider, $filterProvider, $provide, $httpProvider, 
          dashboardResolverProvider, dialogsProvider, localStorageServiceProvider, ROUTER, $translateProvider)
```

Always Remember that here order of dependency matters the most.